# How to get results from "Elastica_ResultSet" object

Tags: php, object, elasticsearch

I am using the "elastica" php client for ElasticSearch.

I'm a bit new to OO-programming, especially in php.

However, I have managed to search my elasticsearch server using the elastica php client and store the response in an "Elastica_ResultSet" object. I have had no luck accessing the contents of that object whatsoever.

I would like to be able to list the total number of results, find an elasticsearch record id of a result and get the full content of an elasticsearch record for that result.

The Elastica class reference can be found here http://ruflin.github.com/Elastica/api/index.html , although I don't know what to do with it.

Here is the php code I have been using to get this far:

```
<?php
function __autoload_elastica ($class) {
    $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class);

    if (file_exists('extentions/' . $path . '.php')) {
        require_once('extentions/' . $path . '.php');
        //echo "$path EXISTS!!!";
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('__autoload_elastica');

// New ES Client
$client = new Elastica_Client();

// Set Index
$index = $client->getIndex('test1');

// Set Document Type
$type = $index->getType('user');

// Perform Search
$resultSet = $index->search('halo');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of months OO practise, it seemed performing a simple var_dump($resultSet) would have provided me with the structure and contents of the returned object... can't believe that nobody made any suggestions for such a basic question ;)

Comment: Another tip when using var_dump is to make sure you have xDebug configured on your dev environment. It will nest and syntax highlight your var_dump() calls and make them a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

So basicaly you can use var_export to output your resultset

But in general the elastica search returns a Elastica_ResultSet object which has several attributes you can use like count, totalHits facets and so on.

and also holds an array of Elastica_Result objects these can be accessed either by calling the Elastica_ResultSet getResults() method or by using the current() and  next() methods or by simply using the php foreach function

The Elastica_Result the data of the results and also has several methods you can use.
getId(), getVersion(), getData() and so on.

```
// Set Document Type
$type = $index->getType('user');

// Perform Search
$resultSet = $index->search('halo');

// Get IDs
$resultIDs = array();
foreach($resultSet as $result){
    $resultIDs[] = $result->getId();
}
```

I would like to let you know something that was a bit hard for me to get.
The query and the sorting of results

```
// Set the query terms for your search
$queryTerm = new Elastica_Query_Terms();
$queryTerm->setTerms('user', array("test", "test1"));

// Create the sorting array
$sort = array("user" => array("order" => "desc"));

// Create the query
$query = Elastica_Query::create($queryTerm);

// Set the sorting to the query
$query->setSort($sort);

// Perform the search
$resultSet = $index->search($query);
```

Hope this helps